# How to transfer Craft configuration changes separate from web conent

Tags: database, config

I am busy reworking a reasonably large website that is already in Craft. The production site is updated with new content several times a day. My current work is an interface redesign. I have a local machine environment, and then a dev environment on the same server set up at the ISP alongside the live production one. The dev will function more as a test server - I can refresh from the production server a few times to test my update process.

My rework on the local dev environments starts with an exact site copy, and will involve mostly template changes. However I suspect I might need to do some database tweaks. In the meantime the live site will undergo a number of content changes.

I am wondering how best to deploy those database tweaks to the live dev and then production servers. My current strategy is to write down what changes I made in local dev and then manually make them on the main dev or live server. These seems a bit dumb unless it is just one or two. I can't copy the whole database because then I would overwrite content changes and I can't put a hold on content changes because my work is likely to take a week or three.

Comment: In the meantime I found this https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2932/migrations-for-deployment/12264#12264
Which I think tells me there is no magic "migrations tool" in v2 (which I am using), and that the manual method is my only really option.

Comment: And then I found this
https://github.com/Firstborn/Craft-CMS-Migration-Manager

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is develop some kind of workflow; the workflow that I use is described in the [Database & Asset Syncing Between Environments in Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/database-asset-syncing-between-environments-in-craft-cms)

But there are other equally valid ways to do it as well. It's really a combination of some tooling, and then just a workflow methodology that you're going to use to keep things in sync.

Writing things down and trying to then re-apply the changes is problematic, because it human error often rears its ugly head when you try to do things that way.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that is very useful. I have a bit of homework and catching up to do with respect to processes. My half baked systems are workable (although perhaps not ideal) for small sites, but I need to up my game for the bigger ones :).